# Parsing Newick grammar using boost::spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

i'm trying to parse a Newick grammar (which is defined [here](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/newick_doc.html)) using the boost::spirit library.

I already made my own parser, which recognize correctly the grammar. Here it is the code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace parser
{
    struct ptree;

    typedef boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<ptree>> ptree_recursive;
    struct ptree
    {
        std::vector<ptree_recursive> children;
        std::string name;
        double length;
    };

    /* Used to cast ptree_recursive into ptree. */
    class ptree_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<ptree>
    {
    public:
        ptree operator() (ptree tree) const
        {
            return tree;
        }
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    parser::ptree,
    (std::vector<parser::ptree_recursive>, children)
    (std::string, name)
    (double, length)
)

namespace parser
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    template<typename Iterator>
    struct newick_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ptree(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        public:
            newick_grammar() : newick_grammar::base_type(tree)
            {
                using qi::lexeme;
                using qi::double_;
                using ascii::char_;

                /* This is the only grammar that works fine:
                 * http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/newick_doc.html */
                label = lexeme[+(char_ - ':' - ')' - ',')];
                branch_length = ':' >> double_;

                subtree = 
                       -descendant_list 
                    >> -label 
                    >> -branch_length;

                descendant_list = 
                       '(' 
                    >> subtree
                    >> *(',' >> subtree )   
                    >> ')';

                tree = subtree >> ';';

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(label);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(branch_length);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(subtree);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(descendant_list);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(tree);
            }

        private:

            /* grammar rules */
            qi::rule<Iterator, ptree(), ascii::space_type> tree, subtree;
            qi::rule<Iterator, ptree_recursive(), ascii::space_type> descendant_list;
            qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> branch_length;
            qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> label;
    };
}
```

The ptree instance, which is given to the parser, stores the newick tree.
The test string, used for this code, is the following one:

```
(((One:0.1,Two:0.2)Sub1:0.3,(Three:0.4,Four:0.5)Sub2:0.6)Sub3:0.7,Five:0.8)Root:0.9;
```

The parser correctly recognize the grammar, but it generates a partial tree. In particular, the ptree instance that is retured, contains "Root" node and its first "Sub3" child.
I tried to use the push_at and at_c methods (explained [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/mini_xml1.cpp)) aswel. I had the same results.

Why the grammar does not seem to create and add all nodes, even being able to recognize the grammar and travel the tree aswel?

Thanks in advice.

**SOLUTION**

```
template<typename Iterator>
    struct newick_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, base::ptree()>
    {
        public:
            newick_grammar() : newick_grammar::base_type(tree)
            {
                /* This is the only grammar that works fine:
                 * http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/newick_doc.html */
                label %= qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - ':' - ')' - ',')];
                branch_length %= ':' >> qi::double_;

                subtree = 
                       -descendant_list 
                    >> -label 
                    >> -branch_length;

                descendant_list = 
                       '(' 
                    >> subtree
                    >> *(',' >> subtree )   
                    >> ')';

                tree %= subtree >> ';';

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(label);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(branch_length);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(subtree);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(descendant_list);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(tree);
            }

        private:

            /* grammar rules */
            qi::rule<Iterator, base::ptree()> tree, subtree;
            qi::rule<Iterator, base::children_ptree()> descendant_list;
            qi::rule<Iterator, double()> branch_length;
            qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> label;
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a lot of cargo-cult coding in your program. For example the variant is completly useless. So I rewrited it a bit, adding comments to help you understand (I hope, if it is not clear do not hesitate to ask in comment). I left the space specification aside as I think it was useless in your case.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace parser
{
    // Forward declaration for the vector
    struct ptree;

    // typedef to ease the writing
    typedef std::vector<ptree> children_vector;

    // The tree structure itseflf
    struct ptree
    {
        children_vector children;
        std::string name;
        double length;
    };

    // Streaming operator for printing the result
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const ptree& tree)
    {
        bool first = true;
        stream << "(" << tree.name << ": " << tree.length << " { ";
        for (auto child: tree.children)
        {
            stream << (first ? "" : "," ) << child;
            first = false;
        }

        stream << " }";
        return stream;
    }
}

// adapt the structure to fusion phoenix
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    parser::ptree,
    (parser::children_vector, children)
    (std::string, name)
    (double, length)
)

namespace parser
{
    // namespace aliasing to shorten the names
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;    
    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

    // This grammar parse string to a ptree
    struct newick_grammar : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, ptree()>
    {
    public:
        newick_grammar() 
            : newick_grammar::base_type(tree) // We try to parse the tree rule
        {                
            using phoenix::at_c; // Access nth field of structure
            using phoenix::push_back; // Push into vector

            // For label use %= to assign the result of the parse to the string
            label %= qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - ':' - ')' - ',')]; 

            // For branch length use %= to assign the result of the parse to the
            // double
            branch_length %= ':' >> qi::double_;

            // When parsing the subtree just assign the elements that have been
            // built in the subrules
            subtree = 
                // Assign vector of children to the first element of the struct
                -descendant_list [at_c<0>(qi::_val) = qi::_1 ] 
                // Assign the label to the second element
                >> -label [ at_c<1>(qi::_val) = qi::_1 ]
                // Assign the branch length to the third element 
                >> -branch_length [ at_c<2>(qi::_val) = qi::_1 ];

            // Descendant list is a vector of ptree, we just push back the
            // created ptrees into the vector
            descendant_list = 
                '(' >> subtree [ push_back(qi::_val, qi::_1) ]
                >> *(',' >> subtree [ push_back(qi::_val, qi::_1) ])
                >> ')';

            // The tree receive the whole subtree using %=
            tree %= subtree  >> ';' ;
        }

    private:

        // Here are the various grammar rules typed by the element they do
        // generate
        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, ptree()> tree, subtree;
        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, children_vector()> descendant_list;
        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, double()> branch_length;
        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> label;
    };
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    std::string str;

    while (getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        // Instantiate grammar and tree
        parser::newick_grammar grammar;
        parser::ptree tree;

        // Parse
        bool result = qi::phrase_parse(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), grammar, qi::space,  tree);

        // Print the result
        std::cout << "Parsing result: " << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << tree << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of your sample:

```
$ ./a.exe
(((One:0.1,Two:0.2)Sub1:0.3,(Three:0.4,Four:0.5)Sub2:0.6)Sub3:0.7,Five:0.8)Root:0.9;
Parsing result: true
(Root: 0.9 { (Sub3: 0.7 { (Sub1: 0.3 { (One: 0.1 {  },(Two: 0.2 {  } },(Sub2: 0.6 { (Three: 0.4 {  },(Four: 0.5 {  } } },(Five: 0.8 {  } }
```

Comment: Hi Johan. Thank you very much for your answer. I resolved my problem using your suggestions: in particular, the main problem was variant usage and the missing % operator.
I removed the phoenix dependency anyway, letting parser to manage the ptree vector automagically.